# Is this shorthand in PHP?

Tags: php

I have inherited some legacy code and I am finding all sorts of weird code.  Here's a headscratcher:

```
if( isset($_POST['name_str']) == 'value of input element' ) {
```

Here 'name_str' is the name of an input element of type button with a value of 'value of input element'.  I understand that `isset()` only returns a boolean value. Here the programmer believes the isset() fucntion will evaluate whether the variable exists and what the value is set to. I have never seen this before. Is this a kind of shorthand?

Comment: No, it's actually a bug that doesn't throw an error. `isset($_POST['name_str'])` returns a bool `true` which is then compared to `'value of input element'`. Since the double equals is used type juggling kicks in and the string is converted to the boolean `true` since a non-empty string is a truthy value. Since `true` is equal to `true` that if statement's code is executed.

Comment: It's just incorrect code, a very common error by beginning programmers.

Comment: Becase `isset()` will produce true or false and never a string value ever.

Comment: FWIW, you want to replace this with `if ($_POST['name_str'] ?? '' === 'value of input element') {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't shorthand, or anything special. But I think it is poor logic.

To explain:
The condition loosely compares whether the value of input element is false or true at the same time as 'name_str' being false or true. Since it is only two equals signs, it will not consider the type when comparing each side of the equation, which is a big problem.

This will be truely when `$_POST['name_str']` is not set and `'value of input element'` is any of these false condition found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

```
the boolean FALSE itself
the integers 0 and -0 (zero)
the floats 0.0 and -0.0 (zero)
the empty string, and the string "0"
an array with zero elements
the special type NULL (including unset variables)
```

It will also be truely when `$_POST['name_str']` is set and 'value of input element' is anything but what is above.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not shorthand, it's just wrong. The programmer's expectation is incorrect.

I see this mistake frequently in SO questions from beginners, it's hard to believe it makes it into production code.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on php.net to indicate that there would ever be a case where `isset()` would return anything but boolean. Reading through the legacy code base is usually a jaw dropping experience. As in .... THIS WORKS?! *jaw drops*.  Thx.

Comment: The client - my employer - could only see whether it behaves the way they want it to.  Their former third party provider could've made a more accurate assessment but obviously didn't care.

Comment: It might seem like it works if the input element always has the same value, as is the case for things like submit buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad coding, 'value of input element' is a true statement if you run it in an if

`if('value of input element') echo 'it will be true';`

So if it isset to anything that returns true, logically you have if(true == true)

The string isn't being compared to the $_POST var.